# What is the benefit of wrapping a method call in a new object?

Tags: java, android, inner-classes

I saw this code snippet in some company internal project, which really puzzle me, and nobody else knows who&&why wrote it like that.

```
private void setDomStorageEnabled(final boolean isEnalbe) {
    new Object() {
        public void setDomStorageEnabled() {
            mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(isEnalbe);
        }
    }.setDomStorageEnabled();
}
```

Anybody has an idea on this?

Comment: Simply its a "Poorly Written Code"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code creates an anonymous inner class and instantiates it, to call a method on that instance. A method which could as well be called directly.

There is no point in doing this, it doesn't add any value. To the contrary, it obviously only creates confusion amongst readers.

Thus the simple answer is: you should throw that thing out and go with

```
private void setDomStorageEnabled(boolean isEnalbe) {
  mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(isEnalbe);
}
```

instead. ( I also removed the pointless `final`, as that *also* doesn't add any value here. Beyond that, `mWebView` could be called `webView`, when sticking to java naming conventions matters to you. )